# Where can i find the support vectors from my support vector regression model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, svm

I made a support vector regression model in R and I noticed that R actually takes my samples (rows) as support vectors instead of my markers (columns), is that true? I wanted to see my support vectors to be sure but I can't figure out how to find my support vectors.

I have used a part of a script I found:

```
w <- t(svm$coefs) %*% svm$SV                 # weight vectors
w <- apply(w, 2, function(v){sqrt(sum(v^2))})  # weight
w <- sort(w, decreasing = T)
print(w)
```

But this shows all my markers and not my support vectors.
I have also used:

`View(svm$SV)`

But this shows part of my samples and all my markers, from which I concluded that it actually takes my samples instead of my markers as support vectors. But I am not sure this is correct.